# What does a "[1]+ Exit 1" response mean?

Tags: ps, nohup

I ran this command to try and get my python program to run in the background and let me exit the SSH connection I am using:

```
nohup python files.py >> files.log &
```

I then check `ps` to check it worked

```
$ ps a
  PID TTY      STAT   TIME COMMAND
13059 pts/0    Ss     0:00 -bash
13327 pts/0    R+     0:00 ps a
[1]+  Exit 1                  nohup python files.py >> files.log
```

What does this `[1]+  Exit 1` mean?

And how can I run my program in the background letting me exit correctly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you use the `&` at the end of a command in bash, it runs the command in the background. The `[1]+ Exit 1` means that job 1 exited with status 1. The number between the `[]` is the job number, and the number after `Exit` is the exit status. If no exit status is shown, it means the command exited with status `0`.

The reason you don't see this until you run another command is because by default the status of a completed backgrounded command is not shown until the prompt is updated. This means after another command exits, or you simply press `<ENTER>` on an empty prompt.

Edited:
You also do not need to use the `nohup`. Bash will only HUP a process when the shell itself receives a HUP. This doesn't happen if you exit cleanly (via `exit`, or CTRL+D).
However you can also use the `disown` builtin to make it so specific jobs don't get a HUP.
Lastly you can also set a SIGHUP handler to disown all jobs when the shell gets a HUP by doing `function sighup { disown -a; exit 0; }; trap sighup HUP`.

Comment: No `nohup` is not for use when the shell doesn't have a `&` operator, it is to immune a process to the HUP  signal  sent when their parent shell or session leader terminates.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Please see `man 1 nohup`, it specifically mentions this. `&` is quite capable of not HUPing backgrounded jobs.

Comment: My man page doesn't. Maybe you're referring to the GNU or BSD nohup man page comment saying that some shells (like (t)csh) have a builtin nohup command that would supersede it.

Comment: What `nohup` do you have?  My coreutils one does not mention `&` at all in the man page.  I don't think there are any "normal" shells nowadays that lack the `&` operator.

Comment: It's not needed for bash, which can `disown` the job via the disown builtin.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas apologies, I should have been clearer. If you exit cleanly (CTRL+D, or `exit`), backgrounded jobs stay running. As jordanm mentioned, there's also `disown` which you can also automatically run when the shell gets a HUP by doing `function sighup { disown -a; exit 0; }; trap sighup HUP`

Comment: So when I get `[1]+ Exit 1`, it means my script ran sucessfully? (Odd, because I think it should take ~5mins...) Also, in order to keep the process running after I quit putty, do I need the `nohup` or not? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @ACarter no, the `exit 1` generally means abormal termination. Programs which exit properly normally exit with status 0. Though the script can really do whatever it wants.

Answer (score 6):

Patrick's answer is correct, although Stéphane's point about `nohup` is important for users with differing versions.  However, the significance of the + (plus) symbol was not given.  Here, it indicates it is the "current" job.  For instance, if I were to submit 3 commands at once as:

```
$ sleep 5&
[1] 29056
$ sleep 5&
[2] 29091
$ sleep 5&
[3] 29147
```

Then wait 5 seconds, and hit return, the output is:

```
[1]   Done                    sleep 5
[2]-  Done                    sleep 5
[3]+  Done                    sleep 5
```

As Patrick explained, the number between square brackets is an ordered job number.  The + is only given for the latest job and the - is given for the job preceding it.  All other jobs do not have any notation.