# Understanding bash outputs when backgrounded jobs are not found

Tags: bash, gnu

When I enter the command:

```
a&b
```

I receive the output:

```
[1] 15872
b: command not found
a: command not found
```

When I enter the command:

```
a & c
```

My terminal's output is:

```
[2] 15964
c: command not found
a: command not found
[1] Exit 127                     a
[1] Exit 127                     a
```

and my text position flash thingy now appears in the preceding position (in addition to the usual "user_name@computer_name>" part) the string:

```
[1]+ Exit 127                     a
```

What do the numbers in the output refer to?

Comment: Possibly related: [What does a “\[1\]+ Exit 1” response mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/69137/what-does-a-1-exit-1-response-mean)

Comment: @steeldriver yes I found a relevant question that explained that the number 127 is what they call an exit code for the case that the command was not found by the bash, but ill take a look here to see if I can interpret what the "+" means

Comment: But I think ideally it would be a good start for me to know what to call the numbers in the first line of all output in both examples,( [1] 15872 for the first and [2] 15964 for the second)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those numbers are most likely process IDs. It would help if you could elaborate on what you need to know exactly.

Comment: Yeah look in hindsight this wasn't exactly the greatest question in history given I didn't even know what an exit code is.